# Django model: sum in def

Tags: python, django

How to sum fields in model?
 I have 2 Integer Fields and want to sum them in def, if that possible?

```
class Blank_list(models.Model):
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='blank_list')
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='blank_list')
    c8_lvl_aw1 = models.IntegerField('К8: 1', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, default=0, blank=0)
    c8_lvl_aw2 = models.IntegerField('К8: 2', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, default=0, blank=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s произвел оценку следующего сотрудника: %s" % (self.expert, self.employee)

    #that example what i'm expect
    def sum_all_fields(self):
        sum = c8_lvl_aw1 + c8_lvl_aw2 
        return sum
```

Comment: Your two fields have the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the two fields have the same name. You should rename one of the two, for example the second to `c8_lvl_aw1`. You can then sum up `self.c8_lvl_aw1` and `self.c8_lvl_aw2`:

```
class Blank_list(models.Model):
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='blank_list')
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='blank_list')
    c8_lvl_aw1 = models.IntegerField('К8: 1', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, default=0, blank=0)
    c8_lvl_aw2 = models.IntegerField('К8: 2', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, default=0, blank=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s произвел оценку следующего сотрудника: %s" % (self.expert, self.employee)

    #that example what i'm expect
    def sum_all_fields(self):
        return self.c8_lvl_aw1 + self.c8_lvl_aw2
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `BlankList` instead of <s>`Blank_list`</s>.

Comment: Thanks for fast response, that what I need!

Comment: What if I have 4 classes BlankList similar and i need sum them? Do I need create new class and sum 4 BlankList's there?

Comment: @KirillRyzhov: 4 classes? Do you mean four objects? In that case you should sum these in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self` similar to Python class to get values of a `Model`:

```
class Blank_list(models.Model):
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='blank_list')
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='blank_list')
    c8_lvl_aw1 = models.IntegerField('К8: 1', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, default=0, blank=0)
    c8_lvl_aw2 = models.IntegerField('К8: 2', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, default=0, blank=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s произвел оценку следующего сотрудника: %s" % (self.expert, self.employee)

    
    def get_sum_of_fields(self):
        sum_value = self.c8_lvl_aw1 + self.c8_lvl_aw2 
        return sum_value
```